# C# - Scroll JS/JQuery luego de un evento OnClick

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Tengo un linkbutton con un evento onClick que hace algo en code behind, pero me gustaria que cuando vuelva de ejecutar el evento on click, hubiese un javascript que moviera el scroll hasta un div en particular.

No tengo mucha idea de js, estuve investigandolo por mi cuenta las ultimas 24hrs pero no doy en el clavo.

Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Edit: Hola gracias por contestar, añado un codigo de ejemplo:

HTML:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" OnClick="lb1_Click"> Click Aqui </asp:LinkButton>

<!--Aqui imaginemos que hay una imagen que es muy grande, y mucho mas abajo mi div-->

<div id=miDiv> Hola </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void lb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //aqui hago algunas cosas, lleno un repeater, y otras cosas
     //y quiero que luego de ejecutar este codigo, el html scrolée
    //hasta el div de id=miDiv

}
```

Comment: Hola Facundo seria bueno que dejaras un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) con tu código para poder ayudarte, por suerte puede que sea algo fácil, pero siempre trata de dejar un código que se adapte y explique lo que quieres resolver, aquí te dejo [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking), por cierto, bienvenido.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Perdona, había escrito antes de leer tu edición... no sé dónde tendrías que poner el código js/jquery, pero seguro que te pueden ayudar por aquí... aun así dejo la respuesta por si pueda ser util.

Te puedo dar una solución **si usas jQuery**. El método que buscas es `scrollTop()`. Dentro del paréntesis va el número de píxeles que hay desde el inicio del documento hasta donde se posicionará el scroll.

En tu caso debes usar el método `offset().top` para que te devuelva este número de pixeles desde el div en particular. (El método offset() devuelve un objeto con propiedades top y left, al poner ".top" detrás obtenemos el valor de esta propiedad en particular)

Por ejemplo:

```
$(document).scrollTop($('#idDelDivEnParticular').offset().top);
```

Esta línea te posicionará en el div en cuestión instantaneamente, si quieres en cambio que haga una transición progresiva puedes usar el metodo `animate()`con la propiedad `scrollTop`, por ejemplo así:

```
$('html').animate({scrollTop: $('#idDelDivEnParticular').offset().top}[,'slow'][,'linear']);
```

Los corchetes los pongo para indicar que es opcional, pero si lo pones obviamente no usas los corchetes. Donde pone "'slow'" puedes usar un número en milisegundos, 'slow' equivale a 600 (0´6 segundos), 'fast' (200 ms), 4000 (4 segundos, etc. también hay una propiedad oculta para el tipo de movimiento que por defecto es 'swing' y puedes cambiar a 'linear', añadiéndolo detrás o cerrar el paréntesis después de la llave sin añadir nada y usar así los valores por defecto que son 400 y 'swing'. Por último también permite ejecutar una función tras la animación, escribiéndola al final o llamándola.

Comment: Jon, muchas gracias  por contestar, estoy recien empezando con el tema del js/jquery, de hecho me vi mi primer tuto ayer, pero ya domino css y c# mas o menos. he visto ese codigo del scrollTop por ahi, el tema es que no sé donde lo tengo que pegar! ¿Va en el c#? ¿va en el html? ¿va justo despues del html del linkbutton? Gracias.

Comment: Segun veo es codigo jquery, o sea que iria entre 2 <script> </script> en el final del html cierto? pero como "lo llamo" luego? es solo la declaracion esa, no? o es mismo la llamada

Comment: muchas gracias igualmente:)

Comment: Pues sinceramente no lo sé. Usando un archivo ".js" y especificando ahí el evento "click" tal vez funcione. Supongo que podrás llamar a una función de c# desde ahí, pero ni idea. Sé hacerlo con jquery + php (es decir ajax), pero no tengo ni idea de cómo se comunica con otros lenguajes... sorry, seguro que te lo aclaran pronto ;)

Comment: Quiero ayudarte pero soy un poco novato, de hecho es mi primer día aquí. La idea es poner la etiqueta <script src="miscript.js"></script> dentro de la etiqueta <head>. Luego en el archivo jquery sería $(document).ready(iniciar); y abajo escribirías la funcion que he llamado "iniciar", donde escribirias $('#idDelBoton').click(function(){Aquí iria lo de mi primera respuesta}); Pero claro, no sé si puedes hacer eso y a la vez que haga el asunto de c# por otra parte desde la etiqueta asp. Supongo que sí, pero no lo puedo asegurar ...